# Filling inputs based on selected option in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, input, autocomplete, autofill

I've 3 input fields the first field is of type select and the remaining two are of type text. Now if I select a value from dropdown list, then the corresponding values should appear in the remaining two input fields. How to do it in AngularJS. Thank you!

**For example** if I select User1 from the dropdown then User1 corresponding email & phone number should appear in the corresponding input fields.

**NOTE: the values are fetched from the database based on the selected option**

```
<select>
    <option value="user1">User1</option>
    <option value="user2">User2</option>
    <option value="user3">User3</option>
    <option value="user4">User4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="eamil" placeholder="Email">
<input type="text" id="phone_no" placeholder="Phone number">
```

Comment: Show us your code man ?

Comment: I don't have any idea on how to achieve this, so please let me know the way

Comment: Can you show us your full code till now ?

Comment: @Loading.. it is just a task, not a part of project.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select ng-options="s as s in Users" ng-model="user" ng-change = "GetData(user)">

<input type="text" id="eamil" placeholder="Email" ng-model="userEmail">

<input type="text" id="phone_no" placeholder="Phone number" ng-model="userPhone">
```

Now on controller

```
$scope.GetData = function(user){
  // Here Please add Code to fetch the data from database. Here userEmailFromDB and userPhoneFromDB are the values that you get from database. 

   $scope.userEmail = userEmailFromDB; 
   $scope.userPhone = userPhoneFromDB;
}
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL ang PHP for the backend. How can I fetch the values and assign them to $scope.userEmail & $scope.userPhone?

Comment: Have you written any SQL queries to get data based on the user?

Comment: Yes I've written the query in php file

Comment: Can i see the code from the php file? What is the function name , what parameters does it take and what  does it return.

Comment: I got it, I use http.get to fetch the results from my database. Thanks man.

Comment: Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.userListSelected = function(userList){ $scope.email = userList.email; $scope.phoneNumber = userList.phoneNumber;

<select ng-model="userList" ng-options="user.name for user in userData" ng-change="userListSelected(userList)">

<input type=text ng-model="email" />
<input type=text ng-model="phoneNumber"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this, may it helps:

```js
$scope.onChangeSelectedUser = function(item) {
  $scope.user.user_id = item.id;
}
    
$scope.selectedUser = [];
```

```html
<select class="form-control with-search" select-picker data-live-search="true" title="Select User" ng-model="selectedUser"
ng-options="u as u.email for u in users"
ng-change="onChangeSelectedUser(selectedUser)">
</select>

<input type="text" readonly class="form-control" ng-model="selectedUser.user_id"/>        
<input type="text" readonly class="form-control" ng-model="selectedUser.email"/>
<input type="text" readonly class="form-control" ng-model="selectedUser.phone_no"/>
```